# Calculo del precio medio ponderado

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql, microsoft-sql

Tengo en SQL 2019 las siguientes tablas:

```
DECLARE @Inventario TABLE(
  Fecha date DEFAULT '01/07/2023',
  Articulo varchar(3) DEFAULT('AAA'),
  Existencia INT,
  Precio NUMERIC(8, 4)
);
INSERT INTO @Inventario (Existencia,Precio)
    VALUES(15,10.50)

DECLARE @Diario TABLE(
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  Fecha DATE,
  Articulo varchar(5) DEFAULT('AAA'),
  Tipo_ES INT, -- 0: Entradas   1:Salidas
  Cantidad INT,
  Precio NUMERIC(8, 2)
);

INSERT @Diario(Fecha,Tipo_ES, Cantidad, Precio)
  VALUES ('02/07/2023',0, 42, 10.70),
         ('02/07/2023',0, 42, 10.80),
         ('03/07/2023',0, 40, 11.00),
         ('03/07/2023',1, -5, 11.00),
         ('04/07/2023',1, -1, 11.00),
         ('05/07/2023',1, -30, 11.00),
         ('06/07/2023',0, 20, 10.50),
         ('06/07/2023',1, -10, 10.50);
```

Quiero calcular el PMP donde las existencias iniciales son las existencias del ultimo inventario anterior a la fecha del movimiento de almacen a partir del cual quiero empezar a hacer el cálculo así el primer calculo sería

### Para Id=1

Ultima existencia X ultimo precio:
15X10.50=157.50

Primera entrada Id=1 el 02/07/2023
42X10.70=449.4

Valor en inventario+valor primer movimiento dividido por existencia final
(157.50+449.4)/(15+42)

luego para el Id=1 el precio ponderado sería:
PMP=606.9/57=10.64

### Para Id=2

(15X10.50) + (42X10.70) + (42X10.80)=1060.5

15+42+42=99

PMP=1060.5/99=10.71

y así sucesivamente. He probado con LEAD, LAG, ORDER BY ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING y no logro encontrar la solución, ¿ me podéis ayudar ?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos el promedio ponderado de esta manera:

- El inventario inicial y precio inicial es el mismo para todas las filas.
- En cada fila, la fórmula del precio promedio ponderado se resume a:

  ```
           (inv.ini * precio.ini) + Ʃ(cantidad * precio)
  Precio = ---------------------------------------------
                     inv.ini + Ʃ(cantidad)
  ```
- En cada fila, podemos calcular la suma de todas las filas hasta la actual, tanto para la cantidad, como para la multiplicación de cantidad x precio, valiéndonos de la función de ventana `sum()`.

Teniendo en cuenta estas cosas, el cálculo resulta trivial:

```
select   d.Id
       , d.Fecha
       , d.Tipo_ES
       , d.Cantidad
       , d.Precio
       , i.Existencia + SUM(d.Cantidad) over (order by d.Id) ExistenciaTotal
       , i.Existencia * i.Precio + SUM(d.Cantidad * d.Precio) over (order by d.Id) PrecioTotal
       , (i.Existencia * i.Precio + SUM(d.Cantidad * d.Precio) over (order by d.Id)) / (i.Existencia + SUM(d.Cantidad) over (order by d.Id)) PrecioPromedioPonderado
  from @Diario d
       inner join @Inventario i on i.Articulo = d.Articulo
 where d.Articulo = 'AAA'
 order by d.Id;
```

En mis pruebas devuelve:

```
Id Fecha      T Cant Precio ExTot PTotal   PPP
-- ---------- - ---- ------ ----- -------- ---------
1  2023-02-07 0 42   10.70  57    606.90   10.647368
2  2023-02-07 0 42   10.80  99    1060.50  10.712121
3  2023-03-07 0 40   11.00  139   1500.50  10.794964
4  2023-03-07 1 -5   11.00  134   1445.50  10.787313
5  2023-04-07 1 -1   11.00  133   1434.50  10.785714
6  2023-05-07 1 -30  11.00  103   1104.50  10.723300
7  2023-06-07 0 20   10.50  123   1314.50  10.686991
8  2023-06-07 1 -10  10.50  113   1209.50  10.703539

(8 rows affected)
```

Comment: hola @jachguate, perdona la demora en comentar tu respuesta, tu solución me ha servido, gracias